# About the distribution of Fibonacci numbers that are primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, sequences-and-series

Let's consider the Fibonacci sequence, that is the sequence of naturals defined by:

$F_1=F_2=1$

$F_{n+1}=F_{n}+F_{n-1}$

It is an open problem whether the sequence contains an infinite number of primes.

It is known that, after $\,F_3=2\,$ and $\,F_4=3$, the only possible primes are those of the form:

$F_{6m-1}=F_{3m-1}^2+F_{3m}^2$

$F_{6m+1}=F_{3m}^2+F_{3m+1}^2$

One could expect that the number of primes of the form $\,F_{6m-1}\,$ was similar to the number of primes of the form $\,F_{6m+1}$, but brute force shows that:

up to $\,m=10$, there are $\,6\,$ primes of the form $\,F_{6m-1}\,$ and only $\,3\,$ of the form $\,F_{6m+1}$;

up to $\,m=100$, there are $\,14\,$ primes of the form $\,F_{6m-1}\,$ and only $\,5\,$ of the form $\,F_{6m+1}$;

up to $\,m=1000$, there are $\,15\,$ primes of the form $\,F_{6m-1}\,$ and only $\,7\,$ of the form $\,F_{6m+1}$;

up to $\,m=5522$, there are $\,17\,$ primes of the form $\,F_{6m-1}\,$ and only $\,10\,$ of the form $\,F_{6m+1}$.

> **How can this asymmetric behavior be explained?**

Thanks.

Comment: $m=1000$ is a very small number in asymptotics, even given the size of $F_m$. Could there be some sort of Chebyshev bias going on?

Comment: I don't know ... the computation is much time-expensive ... my workstation is working on $\,m=10000\,$ ...

Comment: It seems appropriate to gather a numerically significant amount of data before asking for explanation of possible coincidences.  (For that matter, one could also ask why the asymmetric behaviour *needs* an explanation—the only justification given for the symmetry was "One could expect" it.)

Comment: Well, in the context of natural numbers the same simmetry of distribution would be a consequence of Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions ...

Comment: There is already a lot of fine bias (i.e. asymmetry) in the distribution of all prime numbers in residue classes. I suggest that you study the relevant literature, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_bias and https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.03720

Comment: The sequence of n's such that $F_n$ is prime is in OEIS: https://oeis.org/A001605 which also has references.